# Why is my Ubuntu system not using the correct kernel?

Tags: kernel, grub2

We're having a bit of confusion on a Ubuntu remote system --  `/boot/grub/menu.lst` suggests the system should boot into kernel `2.6.35-30-generic`, but it is actually running kernel `2.6.32-27-generic`.  Where should I look to start figuring out why this is happening and how to fix it?

Specifically, `/boot/grub/menu.lst` has

```
default         0
```

and the first entry is

```
title           Ubuntu 10.10, kernel 2.6.35-30-generic
uuid            67717ee3-cbf9-45d2-ae97-820256f4c4fd
kernel          /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-30-generic root=UUID=67717ee3-cbf9-45d2-    ae97-820256f4c4fd ro quiet splash
initrd          /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-30-generic
```

Further, I've confirmed that `/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-30-generic` and `/boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-30-generic` exist and have appropriate permissions.

Meanwhile, `uname -a` returns:

```
$ uname -a
Linux cuda2 2.6.32-27-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 2 00:51:09 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Edit: I've also tried re-running `update-grub`, and rebooting; no luck.

Here's the full menu.lst, as requested by a commenter:

```
# menu.lst - See: grub(8), info grub, update-grub(8)
#            grub-install(8), grub-floppy(8),
#            grub-md5-crypt, /usr/share/doc/grub
#            and /usr/share/doc/grub-legacy-doc/.

## default num
# Set the default entry to the entry number NUM. Numbering starts from 0, and
# the entry number 0 is the default if the command is not used.
#
# You can specify 'saved' instead of a number. In this case, the default entry
# is the entry saved with the command 'savedefault'.
# WARNING: If you are using dmraid do not use 'savedefault' or your
# array will desync and will not let you boot your system.
default         0

## timeout sec
# Set a timeout, in SEC seconds, before automatically booting the default entry
# (normally the first entry defined).
timeout         3

## hiddenmenu
# Hides the menu by default (press ESC to see the menu)
hiddenmenu

# Pretty colours
#color cyan/blue white/blue

## password ['--md5'] passwd
# If used in the first section of a menu file, disable all interactive editing
# control (menu entry editor and command-line)  and entries protected by the
# command 'lock'
# e.g. password topsecret
#      password --md5 $1$gLhU0/$aW78kHK1QfV3P2b2znUoe/
# password topsecret

#
# examples
#
# title         Windows 95/98/NT/2000
# root          (hd0,0)
# makeactive
# chainloader   +1
#
# title         Linux
# root          (hd0,1)
# kernel        /vmlinuz root=/dev/hda2 ro
#

#
# Put static boot stanzas before and/or after AUTOMAGIC KERNEL LIST

### BEGIN AUTOMAGIC KERNELS LIST
## lines between the AUTOMAGIC KERNELS LIST markers will be modified
## by the debian update-grub script except for the default options below

## DO NOT UNCOMMENT THEM, Just edit them to your needs

## ## Start Default Options ##
## default kernel options
## default kernel options for automagic boot options
## If you want special options for specific kernels use kopt_x_y_z
## where x.y.z is kernel version. Minor versions can be omitted.
## e.g. kopt=root=/dev/hda1 ro
##      kopt_2_6_8=root=/dev/hdc1 ro
##      kopt_2_6_8_2_686=root=/dev/hdc2 ro
# kopt=root=UUID=67717ee3-cbf9-45d2-ae97-820256f4c4fd ro

## default grub root device
## e.g. groot=(hd0,0)
# groot=67717ee3-cbf9-45d2-ae97-820256f4c4fd

## should update-grub create alternative automagic boot options
## e.g. alternative=true
##      alternative=false
# alternative=true

## should update-grub lock alternative automagic boot options
## e.g. lockalternative=true
##      lockalternative=false
# lockalternative=false

## additional options to use with the default boot option, but not with the
## alternatives
## e.g. defoptions=vga=791 resume=/dev/hda5
# defoptions=quiet splash

## should update-grub lock old automagic boot options
## e.g. lockold=false
##      lockold=true
# lockold=false

## Xen hypervisor options to use with the default Xen boot option
# xenhopt=

## Xen Linux kernel options to use with the default Xen boot option
# xenkopt=console=tty0

## altoption boot targets option
## multiple altoptions lines are allowed
## e.g. altoptions=(extra menu suffix) extra boot options
##      altoptions=(recovery) single
# altoptions=(recovery mode) single

## controls how many kernels should be put into the menu.lst
## only counts the first occurence of a kernel, not the
## alternative kernel options
## e.g. howmany=all
##      howmany=7
# howmany=all

## specify if running in Xen domU or have grub detect automatically
## update-grub will ignore non-xen kernels when running in domU and vice versa
## e.g. indomU=detect
##      indomU=true
##      indomU=false
# indomU=detect

## should update-grub create memtest86 boot option
## e.g. memtest86=true
##      memtest86=false
# memtest86=true

## should update-grub adjust the value of the default booted system
## can be true or false
# updatedefaultentry=false

## should update-grub add savedefault to the default options
## can be true or false
# savedefault=false

## ## End Default Options ##

title           Ubuntu 10.10, kernel 2.6.35-30-generic
uuid            67717ee3-cbf9-45d2-ae97-820256f4c4fd
kernel          /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-30-generic root=UUID=67717ee3-cbf9-45d2-ae97-820256f4c4fd ro quiet splash
initrd          /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-30-generic

title           Ubuntu 10.10, kernel 2.6.35-30-generic (recovery mode)
uuid            67717ee3-cbf9-45d2-ae97-820256f4c4fd
kernel          /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-30-generic root=UUID=67717ee3-cbf9-45d2-ae97-820256f4c4fd ro  single
initrd          /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-30-generic

title           Ubuntu 10.10, kernel 2.6.32-32-server
uuid            67717ee3-cbf9-45d2-ae97-820256f4c4fd
kernel          /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-32-server root=UUID=67717ee3-cbf9-45d2-ae97-820256f4c4fd ro quiet splash
initrd          /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-32-server

title           Ubuntu 10.10, kernel 2.6.32-32-server (recovery mode)
uuid            67717ee3-cbf9-45d2-ae97-820256f4c4fd
kernel          /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-32-server root=UUID=67717ee3-cbf9-45d2-ae97-820256f4c4fd ro  single
initrd          /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-32-server

title           Ubuntu 10.10, kernel 2.6.32-27-generic
uuid            67717ee3-cbf9-45d2-ae97-820256f4c4fd
kernel          /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-27-generic root=UUID=67717ee3-cbf9-45d2-ae97-820256f4c4fd ro quiet splash
initrd          /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-27-generic

title           Ubuntu 10.10, kernel 2.6.32-27-generic (recovery mode)
uuid            67717ee3-cbf9-45d2-ae97-820256f4c4fd
kernel          /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-27-generic root=UUID=67717ee3-cbf9-45d2-ae97-820256f4c4fd ro  single
initrd          /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-27-generic

title           Chainload into GRUB 2
root            67717ee3-cbf9-45d2-ae97-820256f4c4fd
kernel          /boot/grub/core.img

title           Ubuntu 10.10, memtest86+
uuid            67717ee3-cbf9-45d2-ae97-820256f4c4fd
kernel          /boot/memtest86+.bin

### END DEBIAN AUTOMAGIC KERNELS LIST
```

To add complication and joy to my life, this is a desktop machine in a remote datacenter; we don't have either local access or serial-console access.  Suggestions?

Comment: Can you post the entire menu.lst?

Comment: @larsks: Posted.  Hope that helps!

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? "GRUB 2 is the default boot loader and manager for Ubuntu since version 9.10 (Karmic Koala)." https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2 Grub2 uses `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly question, but where is the problem? Is the kernel version mission-critical?

Comment: @MarkWagner: Hah.  Yes, that would be the problem.  This is Ubuntu 10.10.  If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.  :)  It looks like if I run `grub-mkconfig`, that will (via `/etc/grub.d/10_linux`) find all the kernel files and regenerate the `grub.cfg` file correctly, yes?

Comment: @Joel: Not silly.  In this case, it's partly from trying to get CUDA working, and partly just an "I don't understand this, and would rather unconfuse myself than ignore it" question!

Comment: Is this a standalone computer or is it a virtual machine? I only ask because at Linode (VPS provider) the host controls which kernel it boots to (and you change that through their online webmin)

Comment: @Oli: It's a standalone computer -- but that's a good thought.

Answer (score 2):

Mark Wagner's comment (from before this was migrated from Stack Exchange) is correct.  This is an Ubuntu 10.10 machine, after the switch to GRUB 2, and thus `/boot/grub/menu.lst` is obsolete and unused -- the real configuration file is `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

However, there is an additional weirdness on this machine, as it turns out -- despite what the documentation at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2 says, `update-grub` on this particular machine is *not* a stub to `grub-mkconfig`; it's still the old version that updates `menu.lst`.  Thus, running it did not update the correct configuration files like it should have.

Comment: If the 10.10 machine was upgraded from a prior release, it may not have updated to grub2.  I would suggest upgrade or re-install grub2. I have 3 10.10 systems, one upgraded.  The upgraded system had problems not properly automatically installing linux-image-generic when doing a dist-upgrade.  The solution was to manually install using synaptic.  See https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+question/162951  I did a manual upgrade to grub2.  Hope this helps.